# Couldn't find these debs: linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, apt, debootstrap

Every now and then I'm debootstraping debian into a local directory. Until 3 hours ago it worked fine, however, now I get this error message:

#### Command

```
debootstrap --include linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64,sudo,openssh-server,hdparm,net-tools,udhcpc stretch /tmp/generate-image/mount
```

#### Output

```
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Retrieving Release 
I: Retrieving Release.gpg 
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id 067E3C456BAE240ACEE88F6FEF0F382A1A7B6500)
I: Retrieving Packages 
I: Validating Packages 
I: Resolving dependencies of required packages...
I: Resolving dependencies of base packages...
I: Found additional required dependencies: libaudit-common libaudit1 libbz2-1.0 libcap-ng0 libdb5.3 libdebconfclient0 libgcrypt20 libgpg-error0 liblz4-1 libncursesw5 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsystemd0 libudev1 libustr-1.0-1 
I: Found additional base dependencies: busybox dmsetup gnupg-agent libapparmor1 libassuan0 libbsd0 libcap2 libcryptsetup4 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdns-export162 libedit2 libelf1 libfastjson4 libffi6 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2 libhogweed4 libidn11 libidn2-0 libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libiptc0 libisc-export160 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libksba8 liblocale-gettext-perl liblognorm5 libmnl0 libncurses5 libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnettle6 libnfnetlink0 libnpth0 libp11-kit0 libpsl5 libseccomp2 libsqlite3-0 libtasn1-6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libunistring0 libwrap0 libxtables12 openssh-client openssh-sftp-server pinentry-curses ucf xxd 
I: Checking component main on http://deb.debian.org/debian...
E: Couldn't find these debs: linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

Until a few hours ago, output was like this:

```
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Retrieving Release 
I: Retrieving Release.gpg 
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id 067E3C456BAE240ACEE88F6FEF0F382A1A7B6500)
I: Retrieving Packages 
I: Validating Packages 
I: Resolving dependencies of required packages...
I: Resolving dependencies of base packages...
I: Found additional required dependencies: libaudit-common libaudit1 libbz2-1.0 libcap-ng0 libdb5.3 libdebconfclient0 libgcrypt20 libgpg-error0 liblz4-1 libncursesw5 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsystemd0 libudev1 libustr-1.0-1 
I: Found additional base dependencies: busybox dmsetup gnupg-agent initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core klibc-utils libapparmor1 libassuan0 libbsd0 libcap2 libcryptsetup4 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdns-export162 libedit2 libelf1 libfastjson4 libffi6 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2 libhogweed4 libidn11 libidn2-0 libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libiptc0 libisc-export160 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libklibc libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libksba8 liblocale-gettext-perl liblognorm5 libmnl0 libncurses5 libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnettle6 libnfnetlink0 libnpth0 libp11-kit0 libpsl5 libseccomp2 libsqlite3-0 libtasn1-6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libunistring0 libwrap0 libxtables12 linux-base openssh-client openssh-sftp-server pinentry-curses ucf xxd 
I: Checking component main on http://deb.debian.org/debian...
I: Retrieving libacl1 2.2.52-3+b1
I: Validating libacl1 2.2.52-3+b1
I: Retrieving adduser 3.115
... and so on
```

At first I though that this package is perhaps discontinued. However, after running `apt-get update`, `apt-cache search linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64` still finds this package, so it should still be available.

On a [debian website](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/kernel/linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64), it prints a red `[security]` notice next to the package name. What does it mean? Could this be the reason? How can I continue to debootstrap Debian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stable kernel is now [`linux-image-4.9.0-4-amd64`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/kernel/linux-image-4.9.0-4-amd64), you need to specify that instead.

Better yet, tell `debootstrap` to include `linux-image-amd64` instead of a specific version, that way you’ll always get the current stable kernel and you won’t run into such issues.

(The sudden disappearance of the old package is related to the [release of Debian 9.2](https://lists.debian.org/debian-announce/2017/msg00007.html) today.)